# Binomial estimation from underlying structural model

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

Imagine $Y$ is an observation from a binomial distribution $Y\sim B(n, p)$ where $n$ is known and $p$ is unknown.

I want to fit a model where the probability $p$ comes from the following process. Each observation $(i=1, ..., n)$ has a latent variable $X\sim Weibull(\lambda)$ and the outcome $y_i$ is $1$ if the latent variable $X$ is greater than a given cut-off value $\bar X$, and is zero otherwise.

The problem is to estimate $\lambda$ and $\bar X$.

Here is my first attempt. What am I doing wrong?

```
p=pweibull 
loglik <- function(par, y) {
  n <- length(y)
  ones <- sum(y==1)
  zeros <- n-ones
  ll <- ones * p(par[1], shape=par[2], log.p=TRUE) + 
        zeros * p(par[1], shape=par[2], log.p=TRUE, lower.tail=FALSE)
  mean(ll)
}

# Simulate
n <- 300
threshold <- 1
shape <- 1.5
y <- ifelse(rweibull(n, shape=shape)>threshold, 1, 0)
optim(par=runif(2), fn=loglik, y=y, method="L-BFGS-B"
      , lower=c(0.001, 0.001)
      , control=list(fnscale=-1))
```

Comment: Look at the call to p (pweibull) in definition of loglik function The first argument has to be the variable threshold!  You did not say at what point to evaluate that function, you have only par as argument